# to create a particular procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have to write a procedure pl / sql that:
1)create csv file file.csv from table CITY
2)place the file in the directory C :/ procedures
3)compress the file format. zip

an example of how you can do? thank you very much

Comment: Hi, I've closed this as a duplicate of your first question - if you have any problems implementing this then please ask another question including the code you're using, any error messages, and a complete description of what you don't understand. If your code is identical to the duplicate's then it'll be really obvious you haven't tried anything yourself.

Comment: When it comes to asking your second and third questions - stop. Don't ask them and search for answers first... the information on how to do this is out there and people will pay a lot more attention to you if you don't ask them to do free work for you but instead demonstrate that you're a coder who's stuck on a problem. See also the [help]. Good luck!

Comment: @Ben - I'm curious - this question and the question cited as the "original" are (apparently) from two different users, but in your comment above you said "I've closed this as a duplicate of your first question". I can't see where this user has asked such a question before; thus, I'm wondering about this. Thanks.

Comment: I meant the first question in the question @Bob; _"create a file from a table"_. Could have been clearer, sorry.